# MySQL multiple index types?

Tags: mysql

I've noticed that in PHPMyAdmin I can individually index columns or I can use checkboxes to select fields and then click index and they're indexed in a different way.  Does this mean that if for a given table I have 2 columns of that table that define each row as unique (instead of just a simple single column id`) I should index those together to increase performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multiple-column index can be considered a sorted array containing values that are created by concatenating the values of the indexed columns.

MySQL uses multiple-column indexes in such a way that queries are fast when you specify a known quantity for the first column of the index in a WHERE clause, even if you do not specify values for the other columns.

If you have two columns named `last_name` and `first_name` and you create an index `INDEX name (last_name,first_name)`, The index can be used for queries that specify values in a known range for last_name, or for both last_name and first_name.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

So, it may not be helpful in your particular case. Becuase if you want to query on the later columns (for example: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE first_name='Michael'` or `SELECT * FROM test WHERE last_name='Widenius' OR first_name='Michael`), the index will not be used and the queries will be slower.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding.  `when you specify a known quantity for the first column` - what does it mean a "known quantity" ?

Comment: I found the best explanation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html, but your link got me there, thanks!

Comment: Kind of confuse but helps me! Thanks +1